# Maven shaded plugin replacing persistence.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

during maven package i have a strange behavior. I have an artifact "A" that depends from "B".

Within "A" i have a folder META-INF that contains a persistence.xml, also in "B" I have a folder that META-INF with a persistence.xml.

This is pom's file of A relative to shade plugin and dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycopany</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

How can I exclude the persistence.xml file from "B", considering that "B" is also a shaded artifact?

Answer (score 1):

use a second filtre and exclude **persistence.xml** like this :

```
                <filter>
                    <artifact>B</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>path/persistence.xml</exclude>  
                    </excludes>
                </filter>
```

more details is in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45683587/exclude-classes-from-being-included-in-shaded-jar) 
and in the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html)

Comment: Somehow this doesnot work for me. Can you give an example of "path"?

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found is to Create JPA EntityManager without persistence.xml configuration file.
I have used PersistenceUnitInfo.

Here is the original thread : [Create JPA EntityManager without persistence.xml configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989672/create-jpa-entitymanager-without-persistence-xml-configuration-file?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: This will come in handy for PersistenceUnitInfo:https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.html